# Angular md-autocompelte does not close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

1. I am using md-autocomplete for search suggestion in my eCommerce app.
2. I have assigned `ng-enter="vm.searchNow(searchText);"` function which has the below code.

   ```
   var autoChild = document.getElementById('searchAutocomplete').firstElementChild;
       var el = angular.element(autoChild);
   el.scope().$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden = true;'
   ```

   Dropdown gets hidden and then again it gets re-opened.

   I guess this is an issue related to focus on the input field.

   Any solution to keep the dropdown hidden once the user presses the enter after typing search text.

Comment: Please don't mix up `angular` with `angularjs`. The tag `angular` is reserved for version 2+. I removed the `angular` tag

Comment: Hi .. why don't put a ng-show on dropdown and bind it on a boolean var that you set in your function? .. something like:... PLZ POST YOUR CODE (html and js) so i can show to you